# Domain Access + subfolders + languages

Tags: uri, i18n-l10n, users, multi-sites, domain-access

I have configured website with Drupal 7. Site is using [**Domain Access**](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain) module. We use this module to make something like multi-site. We have one launch page on which you can choose desired subsite. All subsites have the same theme but with different colors, images, content. Additionaly site is multi-language. Right now structure is as follows:

> intro.example.com/de - launch page in German
>  intro.example.com/en
>   - launch page in English
>  site1.example.com/de - main page for first subdivision in German
>  site2.example.com/en - main page for
>   first subdivision in English
>  site2.example.com/de - main page for
>   second subdivision in German
>  site2.example.com/en - main page for
>   second subdivision in English

I would like to change URL structure to following:

> example.com/de - launch page in German
>  example.com/en - launch
>   page in English
>  example.com/de/german_name_of_site_1 
>   example.com/en/english_name_of_site_1
>   example.com/de/german_name_of_site_2 
>   example.com/en/english_name_of_site_2

How can I change this link structure without turning whole site upside-down?
I would appreciate any help and ideas.

Franz